# I am getting the same issue

Tags: reactjs

By using create-react-app it shows "Missing dependencies in package.json" in every try

I tried creating react app
I am expecting all files but I am getting only package.json

Comment: please share your react version, Node and npm version. and make sure that you  are using npx create-react-app my_app command?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer with the limited amount of information provided. One possible issue could be you are using a stale version of create-react-app from your npm cache.

Firstly, check you haven't installed it globally: `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

Then try and clear your cache with `npm cache clean –force` then run `npx create-react-app {foldername}`.

Comment: When doing this I am getting this error

Comment: 'create-react-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.